# BlogOverflow.com

Tags: discussion

Might [this](http://blogoverflow.com/) help us fill the need for a place to discuss?

http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow

Comment: Going over the blog post, it seems like this could potentially tie in to this idea: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/978/buying-the-community-books-to-generate-questions

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of those users that would like an area for discussion with the rpg.SE community.  But I don't think BlogOverflow is the right tool for that.  My understanding of it is that instead of open discussion, there are designated posters who write for the blog.  At best, I feel like we'd get an approved topic or two every day to discuss but there would be no way for an individual to ask a question.  There might be value in this sort of moderated discussion but I don't think it'll satisfy community debate the same way a forum would.

Comment: I guess that the model will be that "trusted" users can post blog items and any registered user can reply in comments.  If the trusted users are keen on creating blog threads as the occasion arises, this might work better than "an approved topic or two every day".  Especially if we have things like: weekly retro gamers thread, or certain users solicit blog posts by email.

Comment: Alticamelus, that makes sense.  I wonder if it would be possible to set up a separate privilege for blog posters.

Answer (score 1):

Blogs aren't really discussion, just people holding forth in alternation, but sure.  If someone wanted to walk us through [the getting started items](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/) in Meta to where we thought it would really be sustainable, we could do it. It would take a lot of commitment, however.

Comment: Perhaps starting after this paper thing gets done, hmmm?

Comment: argleblarglepaper... ::sigh::